# Is it possible to make a new AJAX request to a PHP file based on response, or recall a PHP function after an error?

Tags: php, ajax, error-handling

I make an AJAX request using jQuery to load content from a PHP file that runs a function, passing parameters to that function through POST.

```
$('#content').html('<h4>Loading...</h4>').load('getcontent.php', data);
```

This works well most of the time, but occasionally, the PHP function returns an error (timeout, too many requests, etc...).
Instead of displaying a message and a "reload" button, is there any way to automatically either recall the function in PHP if it returns an error, or make a new request from the jQuery side? In both cases, ideally I'd include a pause of 2 or 3 seconds before the new request.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a couple of ways you could handle this. the load method for one has additional functionality so that you could use it to re-call the file and its contents.

Assuming I understand the issue of course then I feel this might help, Here is a code example from JQuery's Site showing how you could check the status and response to determine if there is an error.

```js
$( "#success" ).load( "/not-here.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not the problem. the file I load ('getcontent.php') always returns something: almost always the correct content, but sometimes an error message because the function is contains fails)..

Comment: I am in the same context saying you get the status aswell, so just check for the error status from the script